# Linux Mint installer does not see fakeraid drive

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation, raid, fakeraid

I have a computer with a fakeraid 0 array (the computer came with it, and I don't want to remove my other OS to get rid of it), and I am trying to install Linux Mint. When I first boot up from the live usb, the partitions on the raid array do not show up in `/dev/mapper/` and gparted does not see them. After following various instructions on the internet (involving dmraid and kpartx) I got the drive and all of the partitions to show up in `/dev/mapper/` and gparted sees them, but when I run the installer it does not see any of the partitions. How can I make the installer see the partitions in fakeraid array once they are in `/dev/mapper/`?